# Laravel Array Element Validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I want to validate that `audition_dates` field to be before `shoot_dates`.

I know I can pass these rules to validate the array:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
      'shoot_dates' => 'array',
      'shoot_dates.*' => 'date',
      'audition_dates' => 'array',
      'audition_dates.*' => 'date'
    ]);

    // The request is valid...
}
```

I know these validation rules exist:

```php
$rules = [
 'start_date' => 'after:tomorrow',
 'end_date' => 'after:start_date'
];
```

But I don't know how to implement them on an array.

Comment: have you tried Validator::make ?

Comment: updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

As for your code, and also as stated in [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation):

```
Validator::make($request->all(), $rules)->validate();
```

We put that at the beginning of our function. You can read more about how to create rules in the documentation link I provided.

To validate before a date, you must go:

```
'audition_dates' =>'required|date|before:date'
```

Date must be according to [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), if you want to check against other fields, it may be:

```
'audition_dates' => 'required|date|before:shoot_dates'
```

Comment: We can perform actions after a we validate a certain attributes, is that what you are asking for? also, if you want the excecution to stop after a validation is false you may do: 'attribute' => ['bail', 'rule_as_you_know']

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I know that. What I want is validation on the array items to be after the date of another array of items.

Comment: I think I got you now with this further explanation. And I didn't mean to insult you with my comment. I know you know a lot of things c:

Comment: I forgot to say I have updated my answer, was it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

```php
[
  'audition_dates'   => 'required|array',
  'audition_dates.*' => 'date|after:tomorrow',
  'shoot_dates'      => 'required|array',
  'shoot_dates.*'    => 'date|after:audition_dates.*',
];
```